# Selenium WebDriver Change Firefox path to Tor

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver, tor

I'm trying to change webdriver in ruby to open a tor browser instead of the default firefox broswer. I'm using the following code and I have a tor browser open before I run this code.

```
path='C:\Users\Bonnnie\Downloads\Tor Browser\App\tor.exe'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = path
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

I get the following error:

```
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds
```

I think I might be linking to the wrong tor file.

Comment: what selenium-webdriver version you are using and the FireFox version..?

Comment: firefox v22.0 it seems and webdriver v2.35

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but yes I confirm: firefox v22.0 and webdriver v2.35

Comment: You might want to check out my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511136/how-to-open-tor-browser-using-watir/19250405#19250405

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me with selenium-webdriver 2.48.1 and Tor Browser Bundle 5.0.3 on Ubuntu Linux 15.04.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

tor_dir = '/opt/tor-browser_en-US'
# The Tor binary relies on these shared libraries
ENV['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']= [
  File.join(tor_dir, 'Browser/'),
  File.join(tor_dir, 'Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/')
].join(':')
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path =
  File.join(tor_dir, 'Browser/firefox')
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new(
  File.join(tor_dir, 'Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default'))
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
driver.get('https://check.torproject.org/')
```

Comment: Trying to get this code to work with Ubuntu 20.04 with TBB 10.5.10 & selenium-webdriver 4.0.3. Had to replace `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path = File.join(tor_dir, 'Browser/firefox')` with `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Service.driver_path = File.join(tor_dir, 'Browser/firefox')`. TBB starts up but them times out with `unable to connect to /opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/firefox 127.0.0.1:4445 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)`. I have tor running as a service on my system but get the same result when it is stopped. Any ideas gratefully received. Maybe Marionette related?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

tor_dir = '/home/me/tor-browser_en-US' # change as necessary
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
options.binary = File.join(tor_dir, 'Browser/firefox')
proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(socks: '127.0.0.1:9050')
proxy.socks_version = 5
options.proxy = proxy
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, options: options
driver.get('https://check.torproject.org')
driver.title
=> "Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor."
```

I had to set the browser proxy to use my locally running tor, as Selenium evidently doesn't use the one bundled with Tor Browser Bundle. With no proxy set I get `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=proxyConnectFailure..`