# How to open tor browser using watir?

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, watir, tor

With my ruby code I want to open Tor Browser instead of Firefox,for this I tried this code

```
path='C:\Tor Browser\App\tor.exe'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = path
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
ie = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :driver => driver
```

I got this error

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:79:in `connect_until_stable': unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:37:in `block in launch'
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:20:in `locked'
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:32:in `launch'
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:24:in `initialize'
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `new'
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
from C:/new_trademap/newTrademapTest.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

What should I have to do ? or there is any other way to do so?

links  [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180686/selenium-webdriver-change-firefox-path-to-tor) [google group link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/watir-general/VxbEtuwg9LU)

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

First, open the Tor browser (it needs to be running already). Then, in your code, make sure to simply start with:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

*In my case: /home/tor/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser

Nothing else is required - don't bother messing with profile

Answer (score -1):

Your path  `C:\Tor Browser\App\tor.exe` is not a path to firefox, it is a path to the Tor executable. What you will probably need to do is to modify your start-tor-browser script to run that tor.exe but not start firefox and then initialize Tor's Firefox separately.

Another option would be to modify your path of `C:\Tor Browser\App\tor.exe` to the path for the TorBrowser's Firefox binary instead, now that the TorBrowser bundles Tor and Firefox into a single executable.